# mutation error, Unknown argument \"barcode\" on field \"createProduct\" of type \"Mutation\" - django

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I am doing tutorials online and trying to make `mutation` works on `graphql` but I kept on getting errors which I have no idea what where the real error comes from and how to start debugging where I have done wrong.

looking at this youtube for mutation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aB6c7UUMrPo&t=1962s
and the graphene documentation http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/mutations/

I noticed that because of different graphene version, that is why I have reading the documentation instead of following exactly as the `youtube`

I got things setup but then couldn't get it to work, when I execute the mutation query I get error.

I have a model like this.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=13, help_text="Enter Product Stock Keeping Unit", null=True, blank=True)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=13, help_text="Enter Product Barcode (ISBN, UPC ...)", null=True, blank=True)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter Product Title", null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(help_text="Enter Product Description", null=True, blank=True)

    unitCost = models.FloatField(help_text="Enter Product Unit Cost", null=True, blank=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text="Enter Product Unit ", null=True, blank=True)

    quantity = models.FloatField(help_text="Enter Product Quantity", null=True, blank=True)
    minQuantity = models.FloatField(help_text="Enter Product Min Quantity", null=True, blank=True)

    family = models.ForeignKey('Family', null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have this for my Product `schema`

```
class ProductType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        filter_fields = {'description': ['icontains']}
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)


class CreateProduct(graphene.Mutation):
    class Argument:
        barcode = graphene.String()

    # form_errors = graphene.String()
    product = graphene.Field(lambda: ProductType)

    def mutate(self, info, barcode):
        product = Product(barcode=barcode)
        return CreateProduct(product=product)


class ProductMutation(graphene.AbstractType):
    create_product = CreateProduct.Field()

class ProductQuery(object):
    product = relay.Node.Field(ProductType)
    all_products = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ProductType)

    def resolve_all_products(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Product.objects.all()
```

global schema looks like this

```
class Mutation(ProductMutation,
               graphene.ObjectType):
    pass


class Query(FamilyQuery,
            LocationQuery,
            ProductQuery,
            TransactionQuery,

            graphene.ObjectType):
    # This class extends all abstract apps level Queries and graphene.ObjectType
    pass


allGraphQLSchema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

as for trying out the querying...this is my query

```
mutation ProductMutation {
  createProduct(barcode:"abc"){
    product {
      id, unit, description
    }
  }
}
```

error returned

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown argument \"barcode\" on field \"createProduct\" of type \"Mutation\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "column": 17,
          "line": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone please give me a hand on what I should try and do?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured my own problem.

There are three things, which are `Argument` should be `Arguments` and under the `mutate` function, I should use a regular django create model so from `product = Product(barcode=barcode)` into `product = Product.objects.create(barcode=barcode)` last but not least `class ProductMutation(graphene.AbstractType):` should be `class ProductMutation(graphene.ObjectType):`

so the code should be

```
class ProductType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        filter_fields = {'description': ['icontains']}
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)


class CreateProduct(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:    # change here
        barcode = graphene.String()

    product = graphene.Field(lambda: ProductType)

    def mutate(self, info, barcode):
        # change here
        # somehow the graphene documentation just state the code I had in my question which doesn't work for me.  But this one does
        product = Product.objects.create(barcode=barcode)
        return CreateProduct(product=product)


class ProductMutation(graphene.ObjectType):  # change here
    create_product = CreateProduct.Field()

class ProductQuery(object):
    product = relay.Node.Field(ProductType)
    all_products = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ProductType)

    def resolve_all_products(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Product.objects.all()
```